# Connection returned by ComboPooledDataSource making no response

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, datasource, c3p0

i am using c3p0 connection pooling for database connection , here is my DbConnection class where i am making the connection to database ,

```
public class DbConnection {
    private static ComboPooledDataSource dataSource;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class);
    static {
        try {
            dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tickettracking");
            dataSource.setUser("root");
            dataSource.setPassword("root");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    public ComboPooledDataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

the connection returned by DbConnection.getConnection() gets hanged after executing 2 or 3 statements .and after some time an error message is shown on the browser window ,

[image]

this is what my log file shows at time of creating dataSource

```
2015-04-15 10:59:22 INFO MLog:124 - MLog clients using log4j logging.
2015-04-15 10:59:22 INFO C3P0Registry:248 - Initializing c3p0-0.9.5 [built 02-January-2015 13:25:04 -0500; debug? true; trace: 10]
2015-04-15 10:59:22 INFO AbstractPoolBackedDataSource:522 - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> 1br4bb8981g1ezhfm6agtx|4f98b5c, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 1br4bb8981g1ezhfm6agtx|4f98b5c, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tickettracking, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 15, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
```

i have tried increasing pool size , number of statements per connection ,closing the connection after use but nothing worked out .  why the connection is not making any response after executing 3(maximum) statements ? Am i creating the connection wrong way or is there something more to be added to the dataSource .i am using c3p0 api for the first time in  my life .

**Update :**
 i am testing my web application on a single browser and 'C3p0 connection pooling can still work with defaults ' was mentioned in c3p0 API documentation .

Comment: Are you being careful about close()ing your Connections? "The full stack trace is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs." Can you show that, and other information c3p0 might have logged at or recently prior to your error? The stack trace above is at some remove from database-related code. It is not very helpful.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hcd9MZQk  here is the complete log file . (ignore the password in the log file ) – @SteveWaldman

Comment: so, that's all stuff happening within 1 second (12:21:25) of application initializaton. there are no visible problems (the annoying `FileNotFoundExceptions` are the result of looking for config files in optional locations, they'll go unlogged in future versions of c3p0). but the problems you described happen slowly, after several user requests, surely not all within a single second. somewhere in your logs, i bet something fails in a way relevant to your application. There is an oddity, in that the config seems to try to initialize itself twice. That might be a hint of something.

Comment: I haven't seen the logs, but are you closing the statements as well after use?